# C#. Как вычислить длительность в минутах по разности между временем в формате - ЧЧ1:ММ1 - ЧЧ2:ММ2?

Tags: c#, winforms

В **textBox1** вносится начальное время - **8:55** (или 08:55)
В **textBox2** вносится конечное время - **9:02** (или 09:02)

**ВОПРОС**
Как вычислить длительность и занести в **textBox3**?
В данном случае должно получиться - 7 мин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместо `TextBox` используйте `DateTimePicker` для ввода времени.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        //получаем данные 
        string inputString1 = textbox1.Text;
        string inputString2 = textbox2.Text;

        //конвертируем данные 
        TimeSpan time1, time2;
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(inputString1, out time1))
        {
            //выводим пользователю ошибку о том что пусть нормально введет время в textbox1
        }
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(inputString2, out time2))
        {
            //выводим пользователю ошибку о том что пусть нормально введет время в textbox2
        }


        //Выводим данные пользователю в формате hh:mm
        textbox3.Text = (time2 - time1).ToString(@"hh\:mm");

        //Либо, как подсказали из коментариев, выводим интервал только в минутах
        textbox3.Text = (time2 - time1).TotalMinutes.ToString("###############");
```

Comment: @koks_rs4per  А как сделать, чтобы в textBox3 отображался интервал только в минутах и в диапазоне от 1 до бесконечности (грубо говоря). Т.е. там предполагается разместить значения 59 минут, 60 мин., 90 мин. 120 мин. и т.д.. А не 01:00, 01:20 и т.д.   Всем спасибо за ответ.

Comment: `textbox3.Text = (time2 - time1).TotalMinutes.ToString("###############");`

Comment: @koverflow, старайтесь вносить уточнения вопрос с помощью его правки.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите структуру [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx). Алгоритм для решения задачи:

1. Перевести строки даты в тип данных `DateTime`.
2. Объявить переменную типа `TimeSpan`. Её значение будет равно разнице времени.
3. Записать в `textbox` конечный результат.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через `TimeSpan`. Только в начале придётся строки сконвертировать в `DateTime`.

```
DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2016, 11, 25, 11, 25, 0);
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(2016, 11, 25, 11, 28, 0);            
TimeSpan ts = newDate - oldDate;            
int differenceInMins = ts.Minutes;
```

Полученный результат конвертируете в строку и выводите в `textBox`.
Если допускается разница более 60 минут, задействуете соответствующие члены `TimeSpan`.
Например:

```
int differenceInMins = (ts.Hours*60)+ts.Minutes;
```

Comment: А зачем тут DateTime? Почему сразе не использовать TimeSpan?

Comment: @koks_rs ну масштабируемее с DateTime. Когда надо будет от часа ночи 23 вечера отнять - будет проще

Comment: Streletz у вас ошибки. что будет, если разница в минутах составит 60 минут и более?

Comment: @4per, нет никаких ошибок. Если предполагается разница более 60 минут, просто задействуются соответствующие члены `TimeSpan` и всё. Сам принцип остаётся неизменным.